# How to post data from iPhone to a web server using POST?

Tags: iphone-sdk-3.0

I need to post two pieces of data at the same time to a WEB server
One piece is image data contined in a UIImage and the other is audio data contained in a caf file.

I am asking for an example showing how to post this data.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `NSURLConnection`. That takes an `NSURLRequest` as a parameter. There’s also a descending class called `NSMutableURLRequest` where you can set the request body and method.

```
NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:…];
[request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
[request setHTTPBody:/* NSData */];

NSURLConnection *connection = [NSURLConnection
    connectionWithRequest:request delegate:…];
[connection doSomething];
```

There are already questions on Stack Overflow on getting `NSData` representation of an `UIImage`, see the `UIImageJPEGRepresentation` function for example.

Comment: And if I want to pass in a single POSt the content of two items, one a binary file and the other - content of UIImage, is there a way to do it?

Comment: You would have to post the data in the [multi-part format](http://www.google.com/search?q=multipart+form-data). Sample code can be found in the [Facebook SDK](https://github.com/facebook/facebook-ios-sdk/blob/master/src/FBRequest.m), for example. Not sure if there’s a cleaner sample or a library that would post for you.